# Magento Preload stucks

Tags: error, loading

when the page is called, no images and no image carousels load. Only after a refresh the contents are displayed. How can I solve this problem?

magezon-builder-preload dosent change to magezon-builder

[image]

it looks like the calls will take place before the jquery is loaded.